# Цвет символа в ячейке DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, цвета, datagridview

Появилась необходимость раскрасить последовательность символов вида:
ВПППВВВнВВВПППн...

Каждый символ своим цветом, для ячеек DataGridView
Никакого кода предоставить не могу, ибо в интернете не нашел ничего похожего.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам придется делать собственную отрисовку ячейки. Подпишитесь на событие `CellPainting` и для определенной ячейки и столбца рисуйте текст посимвольно, вызовами `e.Graphics.DrawString`, передавая соответствующий `Brush` в зависимости от символа.

[Пример кастомной отрисовки из MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellpaintingeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2):

```
Private Sub dataGridView1_CellPainting(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs) _
    Handles dataGridView1.CellPainting

    If Me.dataGridView1.Columns("ContactName").Index = _
        e.ColumnIndex AndAlso e.RowIndex >= 0 Then

        Dim newRect As New Rectangle(e.CellBounds.X + 1, e.CellBounds.Y + 1, _
            e.CellBounds.Width - 4, e.CellBounds.Height - 4)
        Dim backColorBrush As New SolidBrush(e.CellStyle.BackColor)
        Dim gridBrush As New SolidBrush(Me.dataGridView1.GridColor)
        Dim gridLinePen As New Pen(gridBrush)

        Try

            ' Erase the cell.
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(backColorBrush, e.CellBounds)

            ' Draw the grid lines (only the right and bottom lines;
            ' DataGridView takes care of the others).
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(gridLinePen, e.CellBounds.Left, _
                e.CellBounds.Bottom - 1, e.CellBounds.Right - 1, _
                e.CellBounds.Bottom - 1)
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(gridLinePen, e.CellBounds.Right - 1, _
                e.CellBounds.Top, e.CellBounds.Right - 1, _
                e.CellBounds.Bottom)

            ' Draw the inset highlight box.
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, newRect)

            ' Draw the text content of the cell, ignoring alignment.
            If (e.Value IsNot Nothing) Then
                e.Graphics.DrawString(CStr(e.Value), e.CellStyle.Font, _
                Brushes.Crimson, e.CellBounds.X + 2, e.CellBounds.Y + 2, _
                StringFormat.GenericDefault)
            End If
            e.Handled = True

        Finally
            gridLinePen.Dispose()
            gridBrush.Dispose()
            backColorBrush.Dispose()
        End Try

    End If

End Sub
```

Похожий топик на английском SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21989469/set-two-colors-text-in-a-single-datagridview-cell